# Einsicht vs Einblick

Tags: word-choice, synonym

Der Duden sagt:

> **Einblick**: 
>           1.a.(Außenstehenden ermöglichter) Blick in etwas hinein 
>           1.b.(einem Außenstehenden ermöglichtes) Durchsehen, Durchlesen in bestimmter Absicht, prüfendes [Hin]einsehen
>       2. Zugang zu einigen typischen Fakten eines größeren Zusammenhangs und dadurch vermittelte Kenntnis, Einsicht
>
> **Einsicht**:
>         1.a  das Einsehen; Einblick
>         1.b  das Einsehen; Einblick
>         2.a  das Verstehen eines vorher unklaren, nicht durchschauten Sachverhaltes; Erkenntnis
>          2.b das Einsehen; Verständnis für etwas; Vernunft

Gibt es denn einen Unterschied zwischen diesen Nomina?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aus meinem Begriffsverständnis heraus würde ich vermuten, dass die Perspektive sich unterscheidet. "Einblick" ist aus Perspektive eines Subjektes A auf inhärente Eigenschaften eines Objektes/Subjektes B. "Einsicht" wiederum ist die Perspektive eines Subjektes auf die inhärenten Eigenschaften seiner selbst.

Comment: Dann müsste es aber "Klausureinblick" und nicht "Klausureinsicht" heißen. Ich glaube, es geht noch weit darüber hinaus.

Answer (score 2):

Ebenfalls aus persönlichem Begriffsverständnis:

> Einblick

Ist im Sinne, entweder eines Überblicks, oder einer partiellen *Einsicht*, zu verstehen. Einblick ermöglicht also das Erlangen von partieller Kenntnis.

> Einsicht

Bezeichnet die Möglichkeit das Objekt/den Sachverhalt in seiner Integrität erfahren zu können und kann so als Erlangen ganzheitlicher Kenntnis verstanden werden.

Answer (score 1):

Je nach Kontext haben beide Wörter ähnliche oder unterschiedliche Bedeutung:

- Eine Person kann Einblick und Einsicht in schriftliche Unterlagen haben.
- Ein Fenster gewährt Einblick in ein Gebäude, aber keine Einsicht.
- Ein Tor gewährt Einsicht und Einblick in den dahinterliegenden Hof.
- Wenn mir etwas bewusst wird, gewinne ich eine Einsicht, aber keinen Einblick.
- Wenn ich mich über ein Thema informiere, gewinne ich einen Einblick, aber keine Einsicht.

Wie genau die Grenze zwischen allen Bedeutungen jedes der beiden Wörter zu ziehen ist, weiß ich nicht. Aber es gibt definitiv Fälle, wo sich die beiden nicht austauschen lassen.

Comment: +1 Ein schwieriges Problem elegant umrissen. Anders kann man es wohl kaum darstellen. Mit Lexikondefinitionen erreicht man hier nichts.